# Sort by One Column, Then Group Same Values in Second Column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 columns in my spreadsheet, Serial Number and Date. I have sorted the Date column into ascending order already which yields a result that looks like:

```
Serial Number     Date
22222             02/09/2020
11111             02/10/2020
33333             02/11/2020
11111             02/12/2020
22222             02/13/2020
44444             02/14/2020
```

What I'd like to do from here using 2016 VBA is group all the same serial numbers together, having the soonest date of each serial number as the first one, like so:

```
Serial Number     Date
22222             02/09/2020
22222             02/13/2020
11111             02/10/2020
11111             02/12/2020
33333             02/11/2020
44444             02/14/2020
```

So what I want to end up with is a spreadsheet of the soonest dates first, but if there are multiple serial numbers the same, then bring those up the list and group them by serial number, but keeping the date ascending order in tact for them, and the other serial numbers.

I was hoping for something better than a for loop, but my pseudo-code idea was something like:

```
For Each cel in Range(Serial Number column)
    If vLookup cel in Range(Serial Number column) = True Then
        Get Row Number of the Match, Cut entire row, and Insert it below cels row (ie. cel.offset(1,0))
    Else
        Do Nothing
    End If
Next cel
```

This would repeat the process on the newly inserted Serial Number looking for another match, in case there's another one further down the list, it'll catch it. If someone could help me program this thing, or if they have a better idea I'm all ears.

Thanks! Will review later tonight.

Comment: You can achieve this just by custom sort... first dates then serial numbers. you can record a macro while doing that and see what the code is doing.

Comment: That works too. Didn't even think of that. Works like a charm. Thanks!!!

Answer (score -1):

Use the next code, please:

```
Sub SortTwoColumns()
  Dim sh As Worksheet
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your worksheet

   sh.Columns("A:B").Sort key1:=sh.Range("A1"), _
      order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=sh.Range("B1"), order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but this didn't do what was described. It sorts the Serial Number (or Index) column in ascending order, but then the Date column is not in ascending order for the other serial numbers. I want to have the soonest date first. The answer in the comment above will work for me. Thanks!

Comment: Is sorts exactly as the code shows. It sorts Ascending both columns, primary being column A:A. If you solved your problem in a different way, I wish you good luk!